How to set multiple elements conditionally in Polars similar to Pandas?
I am trying to set multiple elements in a Polars DataFrame based on a condition, similar to how it is done in Pandas. Here’s an example in Pandas:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    B=[0, 5, 9, 2, 10],
))

df.loc[df['A'] < df['B'], 'A'] = [100, 210, 320]
print(df)

This updates column A where A < B with [100, 210, 320].
In Polars, I know that updating a DataFrame in place is not possible, and it is fine to return a new DataFrame with the updated elements. I have tried the following methods:
Attempt 1: Using Series.scatter with map_batches
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(
    A=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    B=[0, 5, 9, 2, 10],
))

def set_elements(cols):
    a, b = cols
    return a.scatter((a < b).arg_true(), [100, 210, 320])

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.map_batches(['A', 'B'], set_elements)
)

Attempt 2: Creating an update DataFrame and using update()
df = df.with_row_index()
df_update = df.filter(pl.col('A') < pl.col('B')).select(
    'index',
    pl.Series('A', [100, 210, 320])
)
df = df.update(df_update, on='index').drop('index')

Both approaches work, but they feel cumbersome compared to the straightforward Pandas syntax.
Question:
Is there a simpler or more idiomatic way in Polars to set multiple elements conditionally in a column, similar to the Pandas loc syntax?

You can use coalesce, cum_sum and get: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79287249/ but it may not be considered "simpler". I'm not sure why Expr.scatter doesn't exist as shorthand to allow just pl.col.A.scatter(pl.col.A < pl.col.B, [100, 210, 320])

updated
You can work around pl.Series.scatter() using pl.Expr.arg_true() or pl.arg_where(), although it would require accessing column as pl.Series:
df.with_columns(
    df.get_column("A").scatter(
    # or df["A"].scatter
        df.select((pl.col.A < pl.col.B).arg_true()),
        # or df.select(pl.arg_where(pl.col.A < pl.col.B)),
        [100, 210, 320]
    )
)

shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0   │
│ 100 ┆ 5   │
│ 210 ┆ 9   │
│ 4   ┆ 2   │
│ 320 ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┘

Or, using @Hericks answer you can inplace update it:
df[df.select((pl.col.A < pl.col.B).arg_true()), "A"] = [100, 210, 320]
# or df[df.select(pl.arg_where(pl.col.A < pl.col.B)), "A"] = [100, 210, 320]

shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0   │
│ 100 ┆ 5   │
│ 210 ┆ 9   │
│ 4   ┆ 2   │
│ 320 ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┘

original
I'd say the way @jqurious did it in this answer is probably as short as you can get.
idxs = pl.when(pl.col.A < pl.col.B).then(1).cum_sum() - 1
new_values = pl.lit(pl.Series([100, 210, 320]))

df.with_columns(A = pl.coalesce(new_values.get(idxs), 'A'))

shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0   │
│ 100 ┆ 5   │
│ 210 ┆ 9   │
│ 4   ┆ 2   │
│ 320 ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┘


Actually, in-place updates similar to pandas are supported in polars. Especially, the following works as expected.
df[[1, 2, 4], "A"] = [100, 210, 320]

Instead of a list of indices, a dataframe with single integer column may also be passed. Especially, we can do the following.
idx = df.with_row_index().filter(pl.col("A") < pl.col("B")).select("index")
df[idx, "A"] = [100, 210, 320]

shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0   │
│ 100 ┆ 5   │
│ 210 ┆ 9   │
│ 4   ┆ 2   │
│ 320 ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┘

See this answer for an alternative solution using pl.DataFrame.update.

pl.when(condition).then(value).otherwise(value) 

is used for conditional logic to a column.
alias() 

is used to assign a name to the resulting column.
pl.col() 

to refer columns in the expressions.
You can try this approach in Polars.
For example
df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1, 3, 4], "bar": [3, 4, 0]})    
df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col("foo") > 2).then(1).otherwise(-1).alias("val"))

df.with_columns()

to apply changes to multiple columns
pl.when().then().otherwise()

which works similarly to pandas conditional assignments
For example


# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "name": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    "age": [24, 27, 22, 32],
    "city": ["Mumbai", "ahmedabad", "Banglore", "Hydrabad"]
})

# Modify multiple elements with different values using conditions
modified_df = df.with_columns([
    pl.when(pl.col("name") == "A").then("A").otherwise(pl.col("name")).alias("name"),
    pl.when(pl.col("age") < 30).then(pl.col("age") + 1).otherwise(pl.col("age")).alias("age"),
    pl.when(pl.col("city") == "Mumbai").then("Mumbai, MH").otherwise(pl.col("city")).alias("city")
])

print(modified_df)



I hope this will help you

Your answer cannot solve my question, what I want is to fill the multiple elements with different values.

I have edited my answer - hope will help you
